# Why my live installation results blank screen?

Tags: installation, 12.10, live-usb, uefi

Trying to boot into the 12.10 live installation from a USB stick on ASUS Zenbook Prime UX32VD. After GRUB it just shows a blank screen. It's an UEFI system, so from the boot manager I picked `UEFI: USB DISK PMAP` and as advised in [here](http://webent.altervista.org/2012/09/16/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-12-04-or-newer-on-the-zenbook-ux32vd/), changed the `splash` parameter to `nomodeset`. So the parameters are:

```
setparams 'Try Ubuntu without installing'

    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi.signed  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet nomodeset --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
```

I've already tried re-creating the USB stick, removing the `quiet` parameter and not changing the `splash` parameter, but neither of those made a difference.

Comment: What do you see if you remove the `quiet` boot parameter?

Comment: Change `quiet splash` to `nomodeset` . It should works.

Comment: The same blank screen.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried all the suggestions in [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)?

Comment: I got a bit further by the help of [this question in ASUS support](http://support.asus.com/faq/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=UX32VD&s=411&hashedid=Z9zboGSUuWyLgwXV&os=&no=8AEDC590-B808-710B-1877-4E94E38B8FD9). Disabling the Secure boot and enabling CSM got me past the blank screen to the next obstacle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you disable the Secure Boot as well as Fast Boot as stated in the [UEFI part of the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).